# Find out what command I last ran that starts a certain way?

Tags: bash, command-history

On bash commandline environment, you can do `!!` to rerun your last command. And you can press up arrow to see the the last command you ran. But what if you want to only **see** but not **run** the last command you ran that began in a certain way?

Comment: Could you please modify your question. I is still not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you search history via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and typing some letters of the command and *not* pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> but pressing <kbd>→</kbd>, the command will show up and will not run. Another alternative is:

```
history | grep 'mycommand'
```

This [nice](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-history-cheat-sheet.pdf) history cheatsheet might also help.

Comment: And if you are not looking for the first match and want to keep searching backwards, press ctrl-r again and again. And this is only one of many powerful commands provided by bash history & readline library.

Comment: Considering you have the verified answer, I'll pull mine and if you want to use the `"^.\{7\}pattern"` expression in your answer, you're welcome to do so!

Comment: if you want to edit several command and rerun them you can also use `fc ### ###`

Answer (score 10):

You can show last command run, by append `:p` to `!!`:

```
$ echo 123
123
$ !!:p
echo 123
```

If you want show last command run with certain name, use one exclamation:

```
$ echo 123
123
$ pwd
/home/cuonglm
$ !echo:p
echo 123
```

Answer (score 4):

Every answer here, as far as I can tell, is non-portable. For a portable option, consider the POSIX-guaranteed `fc`:

```
    $ man fc
```

> ***−e***   editor Use the editor named by ***editor*** to edit the commands. The editor string is a utility name, subject to search  via the ***PATH*** variable ... The value in the ***FCEDIT*** variable shall be used as a default when ***−e*** is not specified. If ***FCEDIT*** is null or unset, **ed** shall be used as the editor.
>
> ***−l***   *(The  letter  ell.)* List the commands rather than invoking an editor on them. The commands shall be written in the sequence indicated by the first and last operands, as affected by ***−r***, with each command preceded by the command number.
>
> ***−n***    Suppress command numbers when listing with ***−l***.
>
> ***−r***    Reverse the order of the commands listed *(with **−l**)* or edited *(with neither **−l** nor **−s**)*.
>
> ***−s***    Re-execute the command without invoking an editor.
>
> ***OPERANDS***
>
> ***first***, ***last***
>              Select  the  commands  to  list or edit. The number of previous commands that can be accessed shall be determined by the value of the ***HISTSIZE*** variable. The value of first or last or both shall be one of the following:
>
> ***[+or-]number*** 
>              A positive *(or **negative**)* number representing a command number; command numbers can be displayed with the ***−l*** option... For example, ***−1 is the immediately previous command***...
>
> When the ***−l*** option is used to list commands, the format of each command in the list shall be as follows:

```
    "%d\t%s\n", <line number>, <command>
```

> If both the ***−l*** and ***−n*** options are specified, the format of each command shall be:

```
    "\t%s\n", <command>
```

> If the  consists of more than one line, the lines after the first shall be displayed as:

```
    "\t%s\n", <continued-command>
```

But be sure to use ***-l*** or ***-e*** if you ***ONLY*** want to see/edit your commands. By default `fc` will open the command-list requested in ***FCEDIT*** *(note that is distinct from your **EDITOR** environment variable)* and, when ***FCEDIT*** quits, `fc` will run the edited commands.

Anyway, specifically the answer to this question could be:

```
    % fc -l -1
```

Or with no line numbers:

```
    % fc -ln -1
```

Or the last five commands in reverse order:

```
    % fc -lrn -1 -5
```

In your pager:

```
    % fc -lrn -1 -5 |$PAGER
```

For your last call to `fc`:

```
    % fc -l fc
```

Comment: +1 for effort. However, the question is tagged *bash*

Comment: It works in `bash`, and everything else. The use of `bash` doesn't preclude portability, but certainly developing bad habits will.

Comment: Best answer here and should be the accepted one, on account of the portability.

Answer (score 3):

hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> then start typing the command you want to see. bash will incrementally complete. When you are satisfied, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to re-run it or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to abort.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the last command use:

```
 history | cut -c 8- | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
```

If you want to be able to do that repeatedly, put a space before `history` or
use:

```
 history | cut -c 8- | grep -Ev '^history' | tail -n 1
```

If you just want to see the last command starting with pattern `xyz`:

```
 history | cut -c 8- | grep -E '^xyz'  | tail -n 1
```

But this doesn't work if the pattern would be the initial characters of 'history' and then you would need to something like:

```
history | cut -c 8- | grep -Ev 'history \|' | grep -E '^hist'  | tail -n 1
```

Comment: There's a typo in your first use of `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

```
bind '"\ep": history-search-backward'
bind '"\en": history-search-forward'
```

And then you can enter some text, and then <kbd>Alt-p</kbd> to search for the last commands that start the same (and <kbd>Alt-p</kbd>, <kbd>Alt-n</kbd> to cycle back and forth trough them).

(Those are the default key binding for similar widgets in `zsh`)

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in a file `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Then `source ~/.inputrc` in your shell (or just restart shell).

Now you can type a few letters of the command, and then use up/down arrows to cycle through commands which start with those few letters.